# "Que", "où" ou "dont" ?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, constructions, formulation, pronoms-relatifs, reformulation

Ce n'est pourtant pas le premier été

...que les températures sont élevées, ça n'empêchait pas l'eau du robinet d'être fraiche et buvable pour autant.

...où les températures sont élevées, ça n'empêchait pas l'eau du robinet d'être fraiche et buvable pour autant.

...dont les températures sont élevées, ça n'empêchait pas l'eau du robinet d'être fraiche et buvable pour autant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meilleur choix : **où**
Possible : **dont**
Très relâché ou très (trop ?) littéraire, fustigé : **que**

Autre possibilité : **durant lequel**

Comment: Je crois que `que` est ok ici car c'est une tournure [présentative](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/qu-est-ce-qu-un-presentatif). Même si on l'analyse comme un adverbe relatif (analogue à `où`), il est en fait [littéraire](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A8Q0100) - et même rare au point qu'on le perçoit souvent comme solécisme.

Comment: @mcadorel Bien vu !